# Is there an API for Wireshark, to develop programs/plugins that interact with it/enhance it?

Tags: c++, python, api, wireshark, packet-sniffers

Googling didn't give me great results.  Is there any sort of API for Wireshark that abstracts away from the main source code so we can develop programs that interact with it and deal with the data it provides?

**edit:**  I appreciate the suggestions for different ways to receive packets, but I want to implement packet injection into Wireshark.  Sniffing will be an important part of my project, however I'm not sure that the suggested solution allows for packet injection.

Comment: What do you mean by the data that it provides? Is this the fomatted output? or the ability to collect networking data?

Comment: The ability to collect networking data isn't unique to wireshark.  However, the interface of wireshark makes it useful data and I was hoping to develop a plugin for it.  It seems like a hefty task to sort through all of the source code just to begin though

Answer (score 5):

I use [`pypcap`](http://code.google.com/p/pypcap/) to read packets and [`dpkt`](http://code.google.com/p/dpkt/) to parse.

For example, to use dpkt to read packets from a saved pcap:

```
import socket
import dpkt
import sys
pcapReader = dpkt.pcap.Reader(file(sys.argv[1], "rb"))
for ts, data in pcapReader:
    ether = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(data)
    if ether.type != dpkt.ethernet.ETH_TYPE_IP: raise
    ip = ether.data
    src = socket.inet_ntoa(ip.src)
    dst = socket.inet_ntoa(ip.dst)
    print "%s -> %s" % (src, dst)
```

To grab frames off the wire with pypcap:

```
    import pcap
    pc = pcap.pcapObject()
    dev = sys.argv[1]
    pc.open_live(dev, 1600, 0, 100)
    pc.setfilter("udp port 53", 0, 0)
    while 1:
        pc.dispatch(1, p.pcap_dispatch)
```

Of course, the two can be used together:  (ripped from pypcap's homepage)

```
>>> import dpkt, pcap
>>> pc = pcap.pcap()
>>> pc.setfilter('icmp')
>>> for ts, pkt in pc:
...     print `dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(pkt)`
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

[tshark](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) provides a CLI to much of Wireshark's functionality, if you are looking to harness Wireshark's protocol analyzers and data manipulation capabilities.

If you wanted to do some digging into Wireshark's [source code](http://anonsvn.wireshark.org/viewvc/trunk/), it has several C libraries that may be of use, particularly wiretap and epan. Examples of its use can be found in the [tshark source](http://anonsvn.wireshark.org/viewvc/trunk/tshark.c?view=markup). You have to erect quite a bit of scaffolding to use the libraries, however.

If you are looking to develop plugins, [this page](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/custom_dissector.aspx) may hold some answers for you.

Answer (score 2):

Try the lua scripting that they've got in the newer versions of wireshark.. you can write custom dissectors (for your own protocols and so on).

http://wiki.wireshark.org/Lua

Answer (score 2):

c++ well could not find one.. but here is the wireshark documentation of Python support..!
http://wiki.wireshark.org/Python

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to find any information indicating that to be possible in the [developer's guide](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/). So that seems indicate "no".

Answer (score 0):

Since there's at least [one](http://www.cacetech.com/) that makes commercial products that integrate somewhat with wireshark , it has to be possible. It seems the immediate integration point is with the data it produces according to wikipedia, [Wireshark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark) uses [libpcap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap). A quick google search reveals that there are several [options](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&hs=xUL&q=python+libpcap&aq=f&aqi=g1&oq=)

[Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) actually looks kind of interesting, though it doesn't really do anything to interact with wireshark, but you can capture packets with it.

Answer (score 0):

wireshark uses libpcap, this library abstracts away platform differences in packet sniffing *and* provides a [format for data files](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/LibpcapFileFormat).  that's how I'd inject packets into wireshark.