# Programmatic way to determine how much data is transmitted over the wire?

Tags: .net, web-services, testing, load-testing

I am developing a web service that will need to conserve as much bandwidth as possible as it will be transmitting over very expensive data connections. I would like to develop a series of functional tests, so I can run various scenarios of what might happen and and record exactly how much data has been transmitted each time, so I can experiment with various types  compression and various algorithms and compare them to other runs.

I am running on windows using IIS 7.5 and the .net framework (v4). Are there any tools or built-in API that I can use to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to monitor the network layer itself, as the usual APIs abstract away error resolution and other stuff.  Particularly in the case of TCP, there is a lot of chit-chat.  But that's redundant, because you're only interested in examining compression algorithms to reduce the actual payload.  You can do that directly because you are in complete control.  If you want to record actual usage, use a 3rd-party protocol analysis tool like Wireshark.

Comment: Does Wireshark have an API you can use pragmatically?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198972/is-there-an-api-for-wireshark-to-develop-programs-plugins-that-interact-with-it